# Что значит вернуть self из метода касса

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, классы, return

Нужно было написать работающий класс, который бы считал количество добавленных элементов заданного типа данных. Я смог сделать, чтобы программа заработала, но я не понимаю почему нельзя было просто вернуть **self.count** и вообще интересно, что значит **return self**.

*Код:*

```
class List:
    def __init__(self, type):
        self.type = type
        self.items = []
        self.count = 0
    
    
    def add(self, item):
        if type(item) != self.type:
            item_type = "str" if self.type == str else "int" if self.type == int else "float"
            return "This item is not of type: %s" %(item_type)
        self.items += [item]
        self.count = len(self.items)
        return self
```

*Тесты:*

```
def simple_tests():
    my_list = List(str)
  
    print(my_list.add('Hello').count, "---", 1, 'How many items in the List?')
    print(my_list.add(5), "This item is not of type: str", "---", 'Wrong type added')
    print(my_list.add(' ').add('World!').count, "---", 3, 'How many items in the List?')

simple_tests()
```

Comment: почему нельзя? делайте `return self.count`, в чем проблема?

Comment: self - экзампляр объекта данного класса

Comment: Не ставьте, пожалуйста, пробелы перед открывающимися круглыми скобками, это выглядит странно :)

Comment: Если бы возвращали self.count, то не смогли бы написать `my_list.add(' ').add('World!')` т.е. использовать цепочку из функций. return self для того и используют, что бы позволить пользователю делать цепочечные вызовы

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для лучшего понимания вами приведённого кода думаю лучше привести немного теории перед ответом на ваш вопрос.

**Теория**

Сам по себе `self` - это просто переменная. Она может называться как угодно. Интерпретатору главное, чтобы первый аргумент метода класса был ссылкой на вызвавший его экземпляр. То есть первый аргумент таких методов - это ссылка на *текущий* экземпляр данного класса (что-то напоминающее указатель `this`, если знакомы с C++).

Написанное можно проиллюстрировать примером. Это...

```py
my_list = List(str)  # создан конкретный экземпляр класса
my_list.add('Hello')
```

...то же самое, что и это...

```py
my_list = List(str)
List.add(my_list, 'Hello')  # здесь my_list является указателем self в методе List.add
                            # то есть метод List.add применяется к экземпляру my_list
```

...просто в первом случае `self` передаётся первым аргументом автоматически, так как вызов метод осуществляется через экземпляр, а не через класс (как во втором случае).

**Ответ на вопрос**

В Python всё является объектом. Это справедливо и для `self` - он имеет тип своего класса - `List` в вашем случае. Поэтому метод `List.add` возвращает тот же объект, что его и вызвал. Тогда получается, что в строке вашего кода

```py
print(my_list.add('Hello').count, "---", 1, 'How many items in the List?')
```

происходит следующее:

1. Экземпляр `my_list` вызывает метод `add(...)`, передавая ему `self=my_list` и `item='Hello'`, то есть за кулисами интерпретатора происходит ровно это

```py
List.add(self=my_list, item='Hello')
```

2. В методе `add` происходит добавление `item` в список `self.items`, который в данном случае является как бы `my_list.items`. Также обновляется значение `self.count`. После чего метод возвращает объект `self`. Но погодите-ка... Ведь `self` был передан при вызове `add(...)` и равнялся `my_list`... Всё верно! Тот же самый `my_list` (экземпляр класса `List`) и возвращается, только к нему добавлен новый `item` и обновлён счётчик `count`.
3. Обновлённый и возвращённый `my_list` теперь обращается к своему полю `count`, в котором хранится уже обновлённое значение.

Вот и вся "магия"! Это и значит "вернуть `self` из метода".

Как правильно отмечали люди в комментариях, в данном случае появляется возможность использовать цепочки вызовов. Вы бы могли сделать и так (и всё бы работало ровно так же)

```py
my_list = List()
my_list.add('Hello')
print(my_list.count)
```

При этом метод `List.add` мог бы вовсе ничего не возвращать, изменив лишь внутреннее состояние экземпляра `my_list`.

Если бы в методе `List.add` возвращался `self.count`, то тип возвращаемого значения был бы `int`, а у объекта `int` нет поля `count`. Так что попытка сделать так `my_list.add(...).count` провалилась бы с ошибкой типа "объект типа int не имеет поля count".

**P.S.**

Помните, что не стоит называть свои переменные зарезервированными словами. Это может привести к непонятным трудноуловимым ошибкам в более серьёзном коде. В вашем случае, например, имя аргумента `type` в конструкторе перекрывает имя стандартной функции `type()`. Может стоит переименовать в `dtype` (datatype)?